# 14.04 Google Chrome Audio Playback Issues

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, flash, pulseaudio

So after about an hour trying to find a solution for this problem, I've had no luck.

The issue:

Audio playback in Google Chrome is way too fast/high pitched/choppy.

Steps I've taken to try and fix this:

Website used for the test between Firefox/Chrome: Google Music (music.google.com)

Tested other browsers (Firefox). Audio was fine.

Went to chrome://plugins. Disabled the Adobe Flash plugins one by one to test.
I have the following plugins installed:

[image]

and the flash plugins:

[image]

Neither of those worked. Additionally, disabled the VLC plugin to test. That did not work.

Uninstalled/reinstalled alsa and pulseaudio. That did not work.

Changed sample rate in pulseaudio to 48000. That did not work.

I'm really at a loss for what the issue is. Like I said, the audio in firefox is fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try deleting the google-chrome folder in .config in your home folder and then relaunch Chrome. This way you're starting fresh. If the issue still persists you'll know it's not with your Chrome configuration. If it stops you'll know it was a configuration issue. Deleting a disabling features in a random attempt to isolate the issue could lead you to bigger issues so starting with the lowest common denominator is best.

Comment: I got the same problem here... Waiting for help. I tried what C.Jacobs proposed but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Things to try:

1. check flashplayer in chrome-plugins
2. delete `~/.config/google-chrome`
3. reinstall alsa and pulseaudio

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
   sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```
4. kill pulseaudio (worked for me!)

   ```
   killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
   ```

Comment: None of these things helped Chrome play audio (and I can't say I'm surprised; my audio works fine in general and Chrome is the only application with a problem).

Comment: 4th solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
>
> sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
>
> sudo alsa force-reload

The above worked for me.  I tried everything: reinstall, remove ~/.config/google-chrome, html5 audio, etc...

Comment: This worked for me, but the last command didn't pulled through.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you could install Pepper Flash Player, a safer and more stable version of Flash Player from Google. An Adobe Flash Player Pepper installer is available in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. This installer downloads Google Chrome, extracts Pepper Flash Player and sets it up for Chromium usage.

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem occurs when I change the audio to HDMI after plug the cable and do not return to the notebook's sound card before removing the cable.