# Flash stops responding on some websites in latest Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash

I have a problem with Flash not responding on some websites. One such website is http://www.webupd8.org. The page will freeze for a second or two, and then a message that says "Flash has stopped responding" will appear at the top of the page. I have to click "Stop Plugin" before it starts working again. I only need Flash for some sites (Twitch, Google Play Music), so I have it disabled in chrome://plugins, but it's annoying to re-enable every time I need it.

How do I fix this issue? It's the first time I've had it, and I don't know where to start. Only system stuff that I've changed on this computer is I've enabled the CFQ I/O scheduler instead of deadline for improved responsiveness (add elevator=cfq to GRUB options), and installed TLP for more battery life. There is no /etc/adobe/mms.cfg file, but from what I've gathered Chrome's version of Flash doesn't use that config file anyways.

I have all the latest updates installed.

EDIT: I've tested the beta version of Google Chrome, and the issue doesn't happen there. If I can't find a fix, I'll use that until it's fixed in the stable branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue earlier today, this fixed the issue for me.

> To fix this issue, you could install Pepper Flash Player, a safer and
>   more stable version of Flash Player from Google. An Adobe Flash Player
>   Pepper installer is available in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. This
>   installer downloads Google Chrome, extracts Pepper Flash Player and
>   sets it up for Chromium usage.

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/541811/482035)

Comment: The problem with this is that I'm already using Google Chrome, and thus am already using this version of Flash since it is included with Chrome. It seems to be an issue with Chrome itself, since the issue is gone in Chrome Beta.